# (Django) AJAX call doesn't hit view, form submit does. Why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms

I have a form that successfully hits this url:

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-_]+?)-(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)-(?P<hotel>[0-1]+)-(?P<shuttle>[0-1]+)/add/$',
        views.product_add_to_cart, name="add-to-cart"),
```

This is the form:

```
 <form id="product-form" role="form" class="product-form clearfix" method="post"
                  action="{% url 'product:add-to-cart' product_id=product.pk slug=product.get_slug hotel=1 shuttle=1 %}" novalidate>

</form>
```

However when I try to hit the same url from a button click with an AJAX call like this:

```
$(".book-event-variants .book-main").click(() => {
    const id = $(".book-main").attr("event-id");
    const slug = $(".book-main").attr("event-slug");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/products/" + slug + "-" + id + "-0-0/add",
        type: 'POST',
        success: () => {
            onAddToCartSuccess();
        },
        error: (response) => {
            onAddToCartError(response);
        }
    });
});
```

I am getting an error:

jquery.js?eedf:9566 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/sofia-fall-2018-1-0-0/add 404 (Not Found)

Why is there a difference between the two?

Why can't I make the call?

**First concern:** Can different namespaces be a problem. e.g. I am am doing the AJAX request from a different app template.

Comment: Can you try add this url in ajax url: `"/products/" + slug + "-" + id + "-0-0/add/"`

Comment: @RajaSimon now I am getting http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/sofia-fall-2018-1-0-0/add/ 400 (Bad Request) might this be because of missing crsf token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax post method url missing ending slash. Add `'/'` to end of the url will solve the problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/products/" + slug + "-" + id + "-0-0/add/",
    type: 'POST',
    success: () => {
        onAddToCartSuccess();
    },
    error: (response) => {
        onAddToCartError(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use @csrf_exempt to get rid of that error. But later you can use ajax csrf method for the csrf. ref [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax)